# Git revert multiple commits including 1 merge, and all pushed on origin

Tags: git

I know there's a ton of similar questions but can't find an answer still, I have been reading all the questions and trying reset, rebase -m etc.

Scenario: I just pulled a PR made on Master, but want to move it to a branch to continue development while keeping the master clean for any emergency.

I would like to revert **all the commits from this PR**, while some commits on master were made. I wish to keep the history so that the contributor keep the history of their contribution.

The history looks exactly like this in chronological order:

```
MASTER        PR

   -  merge in PR: f0d3301 (Head)
  |  \
  |    \
  |      \
  |        \
  |          \ 
  |           | 62ed3e9 (last commit on PR)
  |           | 
  |           | ... lots of others commits.
  |           | 
  |           | c6e178e
  |           |
  |ccdad84    | 
  | ...       | 
  |0d16f42    | 
  |           |
  |           | c56f2911 (first commit on PR)
  |          /
  |        /
  |      /
  |    /
  |  /
  |/
  | 8e74cf3 (last commit on master before PR starts)
```

What commands do I need to rollback, keep history, prevent error from the last merge commit, and push back to master while I have the PR on another branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can force push to master, "reverting master" is simply :

```
# reset the master branch on the remote repo to ccdad84 :
git push origin -f ccdad84:master
```

If some other users already have pulled "master", you have to inform them that master was reverted, and guide them through resetting their local master branch to a correct state.

---

To reset your local `master` branch to `ccdad84` :

```
# from the master branch :
git reset ccdad84
```

If you want to store the PR branch :

```
git branch the/pr 62ed3e9
git push origin the/pr
```

If you want to store the PR branch *and* the merge commit :

```
git branch the/mergedpr f0d3301
git push origin the/mergedpr
```

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC, will it keep the commits made on master after 8e74cf3? the first 2 commands is what I am looking for, but I don't know about, the rest is simple

Comment: ah, I misread : if you want master to roll back to `ccdad84`, target this commit instead of `8e74cf3`

Comment: ok, then will it be free of any PR commit including c56f2911 (first commit of PR)? I would like to have the Master at its last stage but with no trace of PR

Comment: Yes. `c56f2911` is not part of `ccdad84`'s history, so it won't be in master anymore.

Comment: wait this will lose the history? reset and force push. Can we revert instead and have 1 commit?

Comment: This will "erase" the merge commit (`f0d3301`), and only this commit, from the history of master. Is this acceptable to you ?

Comment: it just reset silently instead of committing a revert message. and now forced push. do you mind to have a chat to finish this? thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214256/discussion-between-antoni-and-legec).

Comment: in the end I lost the history so it's not what I wanted. But that solved my issue anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rewrite history. If you want to start a branch where the old branch left off, then do that. My advice is to start a branch at 62ed3e9 and then add a new commit to master that undoes the effect of the merge, that is, is identical to ccdad84.

---

If despite what I just said, you insist on rewriting history:

1. Stop all work.
2. Pull the entire situation to your local machine.
3. Start a branch at 62ed3e9. Call it `saved`.
4. Get on master and `reset --hard` to ccdad84.
5. Force push both branches. Alert everyone to start a new clone or whatever.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I don't want to rewrite the history but rather revert all the PR on master adding 1 commit on master that does the opposite code. In the end the history is gone and force pushed on origin from using `git push origin -f ccdad84:master`

Comment: You are saying two opposite things. Force push rewrites history. Decide.

Comment: I did not want to lose history but I followed the advice from @LeGEC answer. not sure I should try to recover history if too complicated, I already have the PR code on another branch.